# A typo-free detail oriented prime conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

> I've grossly overstated things in my two posts before the last one. Thank you for providing references that have returned me to reality.

**Conjecture** For arbitrary integers $\ 0 \le k \le m\ $ there exists
integer $\ n\ge m\ $ such that for every natural number $\ s\ $ at
least one of the numbers

$$\ p(x+s+1)-p(x+s)\ \ne\ p(x+1)-p(x) $$

where $\ k\le x < n$.

> Here, $\ p(0)=2, p(1)=3,\ldots\ $ is the strictly increasing sequence of all prime numbers.

An assembler-like equivalent formulation:

**Conjecture'**

$$ \forall_{m\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}}\,\forall_{k\in 0..m}\,
\exists_{n\in\mathbb Z_{\ge m}}\,\forall_{s\in\mathbb N}\,
\exists_{x\in k..n\!-\!1} $$
$$ p(x+s+1)-p(x+s)\ \ne\ p(x+1)-p(x) $$

> Here (Perl notation),

$$\ u..v\ :=\ \{x\in\mathbb Z:\ u\le x\le v\} $$

Comment: I don't understand the statement, in particular the part "at least one of the numbers" followed by a formula... I would welcome a clarification, perhaps using less natural language and more quantifiers.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch or anybody, if you would like too, I'd provide an Image-Processing/Bourbaki-like terminology for my *answer* below (it was my first choice but I don't mean to write here purely for my own sake)..

Comment: Thank you! It's not that I'm so much of Bourbaki style fan myself, but simpy I didn't understand that "at least one of the numbers <formula>, for $k\le x <n$" meant "for at least one $x$ such that $k\le x <n$, <formula>"...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Isn't it true that $\forall_{m\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}}\,\forall_{k\in 0..m}\, \exists_{n\in\mathbb Z_{\ge m}} :\forall_{s\in\mathbb N}\, \exists_{x\in k..n-1} : P(x,s)$ is equivalent to $\forall_{a\in \mathbb N}\, \exists_{b(a)\in\mathbb Z_{\ge a}} :\forall_{s\in\mathbb N}\, \exists_{x\in a..b(a)} : P(x,s)$?

Comment: @YaakovBaruch, u'r right! ### I had the feeling that the initial segment was not important but, how nice! you took a step back and saw it clearly. Indeed, formally, by setting a=k=m we get your equivalence. (There is often a bit of psychology or inertia left beside the straight logic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like in the previous post, let $q=p(k)$ and let $n\geq m$ be such that primes $p(x),k\leq x<n$ cover all residue classes mod $q$.

Suppose this $n$ doesn't work. This means that $p(x+s+1)-p(x+s)=p(x+1)-p(x)$ for all $k\leq x<n$. Adding up a bunch of such equalities we get $p(x+s)-p(k+s)=p(x)-p(k)$ for all $k\leq x\leq n$. As $s>0$, we have $p(k+s)>q$ so it is indivisible by $q$. There is some $k<x<n$ such that $p(x)\equiv -p(k+s)\pmod{q}$, and we get $p(x+s)=p(k+s)+p(x)-p(k)\equiv 0\pmod q$, which is impossible as $p(x+s)>q$, hence a contradiction.

Comment: This is so nice! You've applied a simple-sounding but powerful Dirichlet Theorem twice (in the previous thread too), and this time this application is even more surprising since the profile definition seems to describe complicated objects, not linear. (On a personal note, I am happy that my intuition was justified -- I just got carried away far too far in my -2 and -3 note, by now already deleted).

Comment: In effect, Wojowu, you have provided a large class of lonely profiles.

Comment: @WlodAA This should be equivalent to "inadmissible" tuples, to my understanding, essentially the "exceptions" to the prime tuples conjecture.

Comment: "This" ? (Let's avoid pronouns -- my general principle for the "Art of Communication" and for poetry).

Comment: @WlodAA The profiles that cover all residue classes mod $q$. I should note that they may not actually be fully lonely - $q$ might "slot in" at different points. Wiki gives the example of $(0, 2, 8, 14, 26)$ (the "profile" being the consecutive differences), where $3, 5, 11, 17, 29$ and $5, 7, 13, 19, 31$ both fit.

Comment: @user44191, you've provided non-consecutive primes.

Comment: @user44191, the primes from your first sequence are $\ne$ 1 mod 3.

Comment: @WlodAA True - I guess I was aiming at a somewhat more general concept, not necessarily requiring consecutiveness.

Comment: @user44191, actually, consecutiveness and extending the sequence assures a full representation of residua mod q. Otherwise, it's not important, meaning that a full set of residua mod q makes the prime sequence lonely, i.e. not shiftable. ### I feel that the consecutiveness is important in general or else we get global-statistical problems about primes rather than local. The consecutiveness may spur new breakthroughs.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTATION**:
>
> $u_0\ \ldots\ u_n\,\ $ and $\ v_0\ \ldots\ v_n\,\ $ are arbitrary finite strictly increasing sequences of non-negative integers, of the same sequence's length $\ n+1$.
>
> $p(0)=2, p(1)=3, \ldots\ $ is the strictly increasing sequence of **all**
> (consecutive) primes.
>
> $ p(u_0)\ \ldots\ p(u_n)\,\ $ and $\,\ p(v_0)\ \ldots\ p(v_n)\ $ are
> arbitrary finite strictly increasing sequences of primes (not necessarily
> consecutive), where the length of the two sequences is the same, namely
> $\ n+1.$
>
> **The goal:** We will see that under certain additional assumptions, the
> above two finite sequences are identical; in particular when one of them is assured to exist as an extension of a different shorter sequence.

Wojowu has posted his answer in the Q&A style. He deserves a more rounded presentation. Let me be the first one to do it. It'll be but a presentation. The results are exclusively due to **Wojowu (Wojciech Wawrów)**.

**Theorem 1** Assuming our NOTATION, if there exists a prime $\ q\ $
such that for every integer $\ x\ $ there exists at least one integer (index)
$\ a(x)\ $ such that
$$ p(u_{a(x)})\ \equiv x\ \mod q $$
and if there exists an integer $\ s\in\mathbb Z\ $ such that

$$\forall_{t=0}^n\quad p(v_t) = p(u_{s+t}) $$
and
$$ \forall_{t=1}^n\quad p(v_t)-p(v_{t-1})\ =\ p(u_t)-p(u_{t-1}) $$

then $\ s=0$.

**Remark** The last assumption can be written equivalently as

$$ \forall_{t=1}^n\quad p(v_t)-p(u_t)\ =\ p(v_{t-1})-p(u_{t-1}) $$

**Proof** (*of Theorem 1*) Let the assumptions of the theorem hold. By the above *Remark*,
for every integer $\ x\ $ there exists at least one integer (index)
$\ b(x)\ $ such that
$$ p(v_{b(x)})\ \equiv x\ \mod q $$

The terms in each prime sequence that are $\ 0 \mod q\ $
are simply equal to $\ q.\ $ If integer  $\ s\ $ were different from $\ 0\ $
then the same prime $\ q\ $ would appear twice -- $\ s\ $ places apart -- in the increasing sequence of all primes; that would be a contradiction.
**End of Proof**

> **More NOTATION**: Given integers $\ 0\le m\le n,\ $ prime sequence
> $ p(u_0)\ \ldots\ p(u_n)\,\ $ is called to be the minimal $n$-extension
> of a strictly increasing sequence $ p(u_0)\ \ldots\ p(u_m)\,\ 
>  \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow$
> $$ \forall_{k=m+1}^n\quad u_k=u_m+k-m, $$

**Theorem 2** For every strictly increasing finite prime sequence $ p(u_0)\ \ldots\ p(u_m)\,\ $ there exists a minimal extension $ p(u_0)\ \ldots\ p(u_n)\,\ $ which is lonely, meaning that it is the only prime sequence $ p(v_0)\ \ldots\ p(v_n)\,\ $ such that there exists an integer $\ s\in\mathbb Z\ $ such that

$$\forall_{t=0}^n\quad p(v_t) = p(u_{s+t}) $$
and
$$ \forall_{t=1}^n\quad p(v_t)-p(v_{t-1})\ =\ p(u_t)-p(u_{t-1}). $$

**Proof** For $n$ large enough all residue classes \mod p(u_0) appear
in $ p(u_0)\ \ldots\ p(u_n)\,\ $ (by Dirichlet Theorem). This, by Theorem 1,
makes sequence $ p(u_0)\ \ldots\ p(u_n)\,\ $ lonely. **End of Proof**